# Is there a way to simplify this while condition (python)

Tags: python, while-loop, conditional-statements

I've been looking for a way to simplify this

```
while bluePoints < BOn // 2 + 1 and redPoints < BOn // 2 + 1:
```

I know how to simplify with strings and lists but not with ints

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, just add some more content: how can you simplify it with string and lists, what have you done already ... Thank you!

Comment: Hi, could please explain what do you mean by simplifying?

Answer (score 0):

You should clarify what you mean by "a way to simplify this while condition." That could be interpreted multiple ways and the answer you are looking for may depend on what is happening in the rest of your code. That being said here are a few alternative conditionals that should result in the same bool:

```
def bon_calc(bon : int) -> int:
    return bon // 2 + 1

def red_blu_check(red_p : int, blu_p : int, bon : int) -> bool:
    return blu_p < bon // 2 + 1 and red_p < bon // 2 + 1

bluePoints = 1
redPoints = 1
BOn = 2

# Your orignal function
con1 = bluePoints < BOn // 2 + 1 and redPoints < BOn // 2 + 1

# Using all instead of and
con2 = all([bluePoints < BOn // 2 + 1, redPoints < BOn // 2 + 1])

# Using custom function bon_calc
con3 = bluePoints < bon_calc(BOn) and redPoints < bon_calc(BOn)

# Using custom function red_blu_check
con4 = red_blu_check(redPoints, bluePoints, BOn)

assert con1 == con2 == con3 == con4
```

[example in python tutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def%20bon_calc%28bon%20%3A%20int%29%20-%3E%20int%3A%0A%20%20%20%20return%20bon%20//%202%20%2B%201%0A%0Adef%20red_blu_check%28red_p%20%3A%20int,%20blu_p%20%3A%20int,%20bon%20%3A%20int%29%20-%3E%20bool%3A%0A%20%20%20%20return%20blu_p%20%3C%20bon%20//%202%20%2B%201%20and%20red_p%20%3C%20bon%20//%202%20%2B%201%0A%0AbluePoints%20%3D%201%0AredPoints%20%3D%201%0ABOn%20%3D%202%0A%20%20%20%0A%23%20Your%20orignal%20function%0Acon1%20%3D%20bluePoints%20%3C%20BOn%20//%202%20%2B%201%20and%20redPoints%20%3C%20BOn%20//%202%20%2B%201%0A%0A%23%20Using%20all%20instead%20of%20and%0Acon2%20%3D%20all%28%5BbluePoints%20%3C%20BOn%20//%202%20%2B%201,%20redPoints%20%3C%20BOn%20//%202%20%2B%201%5D%29%0A%0A%23%20Using%20custom%20function%20bon_calc%0Acon3%20%3D%20bluePoints%20%3C%20bon_calc%28BOn%29%20and%20redPoints%20%3C%20bon_calc%28BOn%29%0A%0A%23%20Using%20custom%20function%20red_blu_check%0Acon4%20%3D%20red_blu_check%28redPoints,%20bluePoints,%20BOn%29%0A%0Aassert%20con1%20%3D%3D%20con2%20%3D%3D%20con3%20%3D%3D%20con4&cumulative=true&curInstr=19&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=py3anaconda&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

Answer (score 0):

Like the other respondents I'm not sure I know what you mean by *simplify*. I take it you do not like the repetition in

```
bluePoints < BOn // 2 + 1 and redPoints < BOn // 2 + 1
```

If that is the problem, you can use an auxiliary variable to store the result of the repeated calculation

```
limit = BOn // 2 + 1
while bluePoints < limit and redPoints < limit:
```

There are a couple of ways to reduce the boolean conditions in the `while` clause from two to one (`max()` and `all()` spring to mind), but I can't think of one that is much of an improvement on `and`. Boolean operators in Python are shortcut operators, so the second condition will in any case only be tested if the first one is false.